# Insert image path(Browse image folder location) in database and retrieve it

Tags: php, database, image

This is the code what I get from google search. But I don't know that will be the img.php . I search in google but unable to do this problem.

HTML :

```
< form action =" img.php " method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

 < input type="file" name = "myfile" />
 < input type = "submit" value="upload" />

< /form>
```

PHP:

```
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cant connect to server.");
    mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die("cant connect to database");
    echo "name:";
    echo $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    echo "type ";
    echo $type = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    echo "<BR>";echo "Size: ";
    echo $size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    echo "temp: ";
    echo $temp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    echo "error code: ";
    echo $error = $_FILES['myfile']['error'];
    echo "file contents: ";
    echo $file_contents = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']));
    echo "<BR>";
    if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('','$name','$file_contents')")) 
    echo "problem uploading file";
    else {$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image uploaded.";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<img src=get.php?id=$last_id>";
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: In this code img.php is use in action. but I img.php is missing. I want to know code in img.php

Comment: your php code work as img.php. you want get.php ??

Comment: When I run this code an error occur "img.php was not found on this server."

Comment: save your php code with "img.php".

Comment: Oww thanks ajay bro its working. How can I retrieve this image via its path which is save in the Database?

Comment: see my answer..it is helpful to you...?

Answer (score 0):

Save your php file as a `img.php` and you have a `get.php` and `get.php` have code like,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){ 
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cant connect to server.");
   mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die("cant connect to database");

   $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id= $_REQUEST['id']");
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result); 
   echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Can't enter in 'if' loop.Why?

Comment: create a `get.php` file and write this code.. if condition for check if request of `get.php` has a value or not..